# Cat_id FROM categories not INSERTING into c_id in subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I was discussing this issue in another question but it was getting away from the original question so I thought it would be best to make a new one.

Below is my code, everything is inserting correctly into the subcategories table accept for c_id, which is being INSERTED as 0 into my database with each entry, here is the code.

```
<?php
//create_cat.php
include '../includes/connect.php';
include '../header.php';

echo '<h2>Create a Sub category</h2>';
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == false | $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1 )
{
//the user is not an admin
echo 'Sorry, you do not have sufficient rights to access this page.';
}
else
{
//the user has admin rights
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    //the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
        Category name: ';
        $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo '<select name="topic_cat">';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
                }
            echo '</select><br />';


    echo 'Sub category name: <input type="text" name="sub_cat_name" /><br />
        Sub category description:<br /> <textarea name="sub_desc" /></textarea><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Sub Category" />
     </form>';
}
else
{

    //the form has been posted, so save it
    $sql = "INSERT INTO subcategories(c_id, sub_cat_name, sub_desc)
       VALUES('" . $_POST['categories.cat_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_cat_name'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_desc'] . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
            echo 'The sub category <b>' . $row['sub_cat_name'] . '</b> has been added under the main category <b>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</b>';
    if(!$result)
    {
        //something went wrong, display the error
        echo 'Error' . mysql_error();

    }
}
}
; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subcategories(c_id, sub_cat_name, sub_desc)
       VALUES('" . $_POST['categories.cat_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_cat_name'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_desc'] . "')";
```

should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO subcategories(c_id, sub_cat_name, sub_desc)
       VALUES('" . $_POST['topic_cat'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_cat_name'] . "', '" . $_POST['sub_desc'] . "')";
```

As the post field for category id is topic_cat

And try to avoid `mysql_*` functions due to they are **deprecated**.Instead use `mysqli_*` statements or `PDO` statements

Comment: I fixed cat_id, still not inserting, not sure if I am making clear, CAT_ID is in the categories table, I am trying to get that and insert it into the C_ID in the subcategories table.

Comment: Thank you! that was the issue, I changed topic_cat in the selection part to cat_id and it worked!, thanks bud.

Comment: @Gautam3164 ha ha ha .. you give me downvote on the right answer.... As you are wrong first time so I give you downvote...